# Full Wave Rectifier Efficiency

Tags: power, ac-dc, conversion

I was readings [this article](http://www.visionics.a.se/html/curriculum/Experiments/FW%20Rectifier/Full%20Wave%20Rectifier1.html) and extracted from it that "The maximum efficiency of a Full Wave Rectifier is 81.2%". Is that true, or alternatively is there some other fundamental limit on AC/DC conversion efficiency?

Since FWR is the canonical stage in converting AC to DC, does it stand to reason that any DC-operating electronics that are not run from battery power intrinsically wastes *at least* 18.8% of the energy delivered to it by the grid? That sounds crazy to me, what am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The writer of your reference article has himself defined the efficiency differently than usually. In his lossless circuit (=transformer, diodes, resistive load) all power taken from the mains voltage goes to the load, but only 81.2 percent of it is DC, the rest is the AC component. The load gets it, too. It's not wasted as dissipation in the rectifying circuit.

Writer's definition has some meaning, if we could have a filter that only removes the AC component from the output voltage without any side effects. Inserting that filter causes the power to the same resistive load drop 18.8%. Is that drop lost as thermal dissipation -yes, if the filter dissipates it.

In practical circuits, especially if the  filter is not dissipative, then the power drop is difficult to to know without complex calculations.

ADDENDUM: Commentator @Dave Tweed is right. A lossless filter and diodes interact non-linearly, waveforms get distorted and the action changes radically when compared to original with resistive only loading => the presented "efficiency" 81.2% loses its meaning.

Comment: Actually, the power still is taken from the mains AC voltage -- as the diode conduction period changes as an effect of the non-dissipative filter, so does the peak value of the current that's drawn. Total power remains essentially the same, but the current waveform becomes highly distorted with respect to the voltage waveform.

Comment: @DaveTweed thanks for the rectifying my lossy writing.

Answer (score 2):

The efficiency of the full bridge rectifier will depend fully on the input power to output power ratio across the unit. The only way that a maximum efficiency can be stated is to specify a limit of the input voltage.

After all, the primary loss in the full bridge rectifier is the two forward voltage drops of the currently conducting diodes in the bridge. As the input voltage increases the voltage drops in the rectifier become less and less in proportion. this means that if you had diodes with sufficient voltage and current ratings that the efficiency can get higher and higher as the input voltage increases.

Note that in my discussion I am referring to a full bridge rectifier built with four diodes so that it can be used with a transformer secondary that does not have a center tap. If you use transformer with a center tap you can make a full wave rectifier with just two diodes instead of four like a full wave bridge requires. As such the center tapped transformer solution can realize a higher efficiency because there is only one diode forward voltage drop in the regulator at a time instead of the two.

Comment: Also as a side note, there are bridgeless PFC topologies, as well as active (e.g. MOSFET bridges) that can improve the efficiency over a standard diode bridge.

Answer (score 1):

If we take efficiency as:

100% x power out / power in

then a bridge rectifier is quite a bit more efficient than 80%.  [example](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/650y2m/full_bridge_rectifier_power_dissipation/)

In the linked example, based on voltmeter measurements, the questioner calculates that he might need 386 watts of heat sink.  The person who answered points out that it's actually 67 watts.

The power efficiency of the bridge rectifier in that case would be (with numbers rounded for ease of arithmetic):

100% x (1400 - 70) / 1400 = 95%

That's more in keeping with what I have seen in the power supplies I have worked with.